# VB Net What is the fastest way to generate object created programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I have create an application that need to generate about 100 to 1000 object programmatically. This object will be generated with the same amount in the database. In order to accomplish objective above, of course i need to call the data from database, then i looping through each data to generate each object. But it takes such a very long time before it done. I hoping that you have an alternative way beside how i do this.

Below is my code to call the data from database

```
    Dim tbls As New DataTable
    Using cons As New SqlConnection(stringconnection)
        Dim sqls = "select * from tbsectiondetail where IDSection = '" & txtIDSection.Text &
        "' AND KodeLocation like '%" & txtCari.Text &
        "%' AND Status like '%" & cbStatus.Text &
        "%' ORDER BY Status DESC"
        Dim adps As New SqlDataAdapter(sqls, cons)

        adps.Fill(tbls)

        adps.Dispose()
        cons.Dispose()
    End Using
```

If i just generate the data only, its just take only 1 to 2 second. So i don't think there is problem about how i call the data from database

And below is how i generate the object through looping the data

```
    Dim resultsx As DataRow() = tbls.Select("")

    If resultsx.Count > 0 Then

        For iX = 0 To resultsx.Count - 1

            'CREATE A VARIABLE
            Dim IDSectionDetail = resultsx(iX)("IDSectionDetail").ToString
            Dim NamaLocation = resultsx(iX)("NamaLocation").ToString
            Dim SectionKode = resultsx(iX)("KodeLocation").ToString
            Dim StatusSection = resultsx(iX)("Status").ToString
            Dim StatusSectionAt = resultsx(iX)("StatusAt").ToString

            Dim StatusC1 = resultsx(iX)("StatusC1").ToString
            Dim StatusC2 = resultsx(iX)("StatusC2").ToString

            'GENERATE A PANEL
            Dim pnlContainer As New Panel
            pnlContainer.Size = New Size(290, 200)

            Tablex.Controls.Add(pnlContainer, curColumn, rowNo)
            pnlContainer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

            Dim pnlHeader As New Panel
            pnlContainer.Controls.Add(pnlHeader)
            pnlHeader.Dock = DockStyle.Top
            pnlHeader.Size = New Size(pnlContainer.Width, 35)
            If StatusSection = "Open" Then
                pnlHeader.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
            Else
                pnlHeader.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(185, 58, 50)
            End If

            pnlContainer.Controls.SetChildIndex(pnlHeader, 2)

            'GENERATE LABEL HEADER
            Dim lblHeader As New Label
            lblHeader.Text = NamaLocation & " - " & SectionKode
            pnlHeader.Controls.Add(lblHeader)
            lblHeader.Font = New Font("Century Gothic", 9, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
            lblHeader.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblHeader.Location = New Point(8, 7)
            lblHeader.AutoSize = True

            'GENERATE LABEL STATUS
            Dim lblStatus As New Label
            lblStatus.Text = "Status : " & StatusSection
            pnlHeader.Controls.Add(lblStatus)
            lblStatus.Font = New Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblStatus.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            lblStatus.Height = pnlHeader.Height
            lblStatus.Dock = DockStyle.Right
            lblStatus.AutoSize = True

            'GENERATE PANEL FOOTER
            Dim pnlFooter As New Panel
            pnlContainer.Controls.Add(pnlFooter)
            pnlFooter.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            pnlFooter.Size = New Size(pnlFooter.Width, 35)
            pnlFooter.BackColor = Color.White
            pnlContainer.Controls.SetChildIndex(pnlFooter, 0)

            'GENERATE BUTTON DETAIL
            Dim btnDetail As New Button
            pnlFooter.Controls.Add(btnDetail)
            btnDetail.Name = "btn" & SectionKode
            btnDetail.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            btnDetail.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(46, 74, 98)
            btnDetail.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1
            btnDetail.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Gold
            btnDetail.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Gold
            btnDetail.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
            btnDetail.Text = "Detail"
            btnDetail.Image = My.Resources.search2_icon
            btnDetail.Font = New Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
            btnDetail.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage
            btnDetail.Location = New Point(181, 84)
            btnDetail.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right And AnchorStyles.Top
            btnDetail.Size = New Size(75, 28)
            btnDetail.ForeColor = Color.White
            AddHandler btnDetail.Click, Sub() DetailSection(IDSectionDetail, SectionKode)             


            curColumn += 1
            If curColumn >= 5 Then
                curColumn = 0
                RowCount += 1
                Tablex.RowCount = RowCount
                rowNo += 1
            End If

        Next

    End If
    pnlFill.Controls.Add(Tablex)
```

Actually there is still more object to generate through that looping. But from my analysis, the looping already take such a long time already just from code above.

[The result of the generated object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkAdi.png)

I just wonder if there is another and faster alternative to generate such object. Or do i need to give up to design and just make it simple black and white ?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection.  1000 objects should be almost instant.  Use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate on your container control to turn off any refresh updates to the control until your loop is completed.

Comment: You should not be creating all those individual controls each time. Star by designing a user control that will represent a single record. You should have all the configuration of the child controls in that and a constructor that allows you to simply pass in the data. Your loop then simplifies to creating one user control per record. Add those controls to a list as you create them, then add them all to a `FlowLayoutPanel` with a single call to `AddRange`.

Comment: @LarsTech Iam use panel as the control, so there no begin and end update, so instead iam using SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout. but there still take such a long time to

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry i don't quite understand what you mean here. do i need to design user control manually or generate programmatically ? and how do i loop create user control ?

Comment: You ought to learn [what a user control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) is first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hey, i have tried your suggestion to design the user control first. and then try to loop the design only to as many as data in my database. for the first 100 to 300 data looping , its work perfectly with approximately 2-10 second. but when the data exceed 400, the program itself break, its error like not responding or the program itself stop working. lol. or is is a bad idea to show all the data in a single run ? or do you have another alternative ? thanks

Comment: Having a lot of controls on a form can slow things down although I'm not sure what numbers are reasonable as I've never tested the limits myself.  Given the volume of data and the issues you're having, it sounds like it might be a good idea to display data in pages.  You could still retrieve all the data in one go but only display, say, 25 records at a time and let the user navigate one record or one page at a time.

Comment: I was referring to the TableLayoutPanel.  If you are getting close to 10k window controls, you have way too many.  Consider painting as much as you can instead of using those labels, etc.